# Как удалить рекламный блок, установленный на все страницы сайта?

Tags: веб-программирование

Как удалить рекламный блок, установленный на все страницы сайта?

Comment: Может опишите поподробней...Нет ну серьёзно вопрос "не о чём".

Comment: Установил два раза счетчик Log.XP (автоматом на все страницы) сайта http://монк.рф. Хочу один счетчик убрать, как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я в Опере для этого использую `клик правой кнопкой мыши => настройки для сайта => Вид => моя таблица стилей` в ней(таблице стилей - обычный css файл) я на DOM элемент содержащий рекламный баннер добавляю свойство `display: none;`

Пример для [rutracker.org](http://rutracker.org/forum/index.php):

```
#ddest-bn-1
{
    display: none;
}
#glad-idx
{
    display: none;
}
#bn-bot-wrap
{
    display: none;
}
.tCenter.bCenter
{
    display: none;
}
#idx-3
{
    display:none;
}
#owo-idx-5
{
    display:none;
}
#bn-tio-1
{
    display:none;
}
#adriver-240x120
{
    display:none;
}
```

для этого в FireFox существует дополнение **Stylish**, на счёт других браузеров не знаю

Answer (score 0):

да вопрос без конкретики, тогда и ответ такой - adblock для firefox :)
или же сайт ваш? но сделан например на ucoz и теперь там болтается рекалмный блок?) а может бесплатный хостинг вешает рекламу на сайт? вобщем ничего не ясно.